# cut a file given in parameter

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm kinda new with Batch or Powershell, so I come here to have your help.

I have a file that is a composition of some files and I want to cut them in different files.

The big file look like this

```
X1
Y1
LINE1 1
LINE1 2
...
LINE1 8
FILELINE1 1
FILELINE1 2
...
FILELINE1 X1*Y1
X2
Y2
LINE2 1
LINE2 2
...
LINE2 8
FILELINE2 1
FILELINE2 2
...
FILELINE2 X2*Y2
```

and so on.
And i'm trying to create a new file for each. (So, for my example, i will have 1 file that contains the first X1*Y1+10 lines, the 2nd file will contains the X1*Y1+10+1th to the X1*Y1+10+1+X2*Y2+10th lines).

My first idea was to take X1, to remove the first line of the file, to take Y1, then delete the first line again, then copy the X1*Y1+8 first lines in a file, delete thoses line in the original file, and so on until i found EOF.

The problem is that i don't understand how batch works :/

(actually i have the code :

```
   setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set first=1
for /f "delims=" %%i in (%1) do (
    if !first!==1 echo %%i
    set X = %%i
    set first=0
)
more /E +1 %1 > %1.tmp
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set first=1
for /f "delims=" %%i in (%1.tmp) do (
    if !first!==1 echo %%i
    set Y = %%i
    set first=0
)
```

That give me first X and first Y, but I think it's going nowhere...

Thanks a lot for reading!

EDIT : 
I want to create files that contains :

file1 :

```
X1
Y1
LINE1 1
LINE1 2
...
LINE1 8
FILELINE1 1
FILELINE1 2
...
FILELINE1 X1*Y1
```

file2 :

```
X2
Y2
LINE2 1
LINE2 2
...
LINE2 8
FILELINE2 1
FILELINE2 2
...
FILELINE2 X2*Y2
```

...

Comment: Can you rewrite your explanation of how you want to split the file?  I've read it two or three times and have no idea what you're trying to do here.  Do you want to split on lines that start with X# or Y#, then grab all the lines to the next instance of X#?

Comment: Sorry, i will rewrite it.

Comment: I'm trying to decompose the big file into several "little file" since the big file is an association of those several "little file"

Comment: So `X1`, `Y1`, `X1*Y1`, etc., occur litterally in the text file?

Comment: X1 and Y1 appear in the text file. Then I calculate X1 * Y1 to know how much line the first little file contains, so i can copy-paste (X1 * Y1) + 10 lines in the first little file. And then the second little file begin with X2 and Y2 of this file, so i can copy again X2*Y2 + 10 lines in the second little file, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, your file is composed of a succession of:

```
X
Y
<Text block>
<Second text block>
```

Where `X` and `Y` are integers, `<Text block>` is composed of exactly 8 lines, and `<Second text block>` is composed of `X` times `Y` lines.

If that's the case, then the following PS code might do the trick:

```
# Open the file
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText("D:\test.log")
try{
    $x = -1
    $y = -1
    $linesToCopy = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    $currentLine = 0
    $id = 0
    # Loop on the contents of the file
    for() {
        $line = $reader.ReadLine()
        if ($line -eq $null) { break }
        if($x -eq -1)
        {
            # Store X as an integer, as well as in the "buffer"
            $x = [int]$line
            $linesToCopy.add($line)
        }
        elseif($y -eq -1)
        {
            # Store Y as an integer, as well as in the "buffer"
            $y = [int]$line
            $linesToCopy.add($line)
            $TotalLinesTocopy = $x*$y+8
            # We're going to copy the X*Y+8 following lines 
            # (we've already stored the first two ones)
            Write-Host "TotalLinesTocopy = $TotalLinesTocopy"
        }
        else
        {

            if($currentLine -lt $TotalLinesTocopy)
            {
                $linesToCopy.add($line)
                $currentLine++
            }
            else
            {
                # Dump the "buffer" to file
                $linesToCopy | Out-File -filepath ("d:\test{0}.log" -f $id) -Force
                # Reinitialize everything
                $id++
                $linesToCopy = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
                $currentLine = 0
                $x = [int]$line
                $y = -1
                $linesToCopy.add($line) 
            }
        }
    }
}finally{
    # During the final loop, we'll reach the finally block 
    # before dumping the final buffer
    # So, dump it now
    if($linesToCopy -ne $null)
    {
        $linesToCopy | Out-File -filepath ("d:\test{0}.log" -f $id) -Force
    }
    $reader.close()
}
```

Side note: I would *never* attempt to do the same thing in batch, so please don't ask ;)

Comment: It's exactly that! The idea is here, but it doesn't seem to work ... :/ My filename is ptxmult2i.ptx and i want to create 1.ptx, 2.ptx, 3.ptx ... . I think the problem come from the filenames, no? (i modiffied ("D:\test.log") with ("ptxmult2i.ptx) and the "d:\test{0}.log" with "tmp{0}.ptx". 
Sorry if I don't know how does it works, i never ever worked on powershell. (Actually with my batch version, I can create the first file... I have to create a while loop now ...)

Comment: Nope, I have no error. But i have no output neither :/

Comment: Oh so you're using relative paths? Can you test with absolute ones, just to eliminate that potential issue?

Comment: I'll try later! I keep you informed! Thanks for all! :) (I have no more computer actually :/)

Comment: So I tried it at home, and I have severals errors, such as "$reader isn't recognize ...."  same for try{ ... I think command of powershell are not recognized. I must do something wrong...

Comment: Are you launching it in a Powershell console?

Comment: Even in powershell console. Maybe something isn't installed... But anyways, I did it using only batch :/ It works since this morning... This is not fast and not optimized but it works (for the moment) well... 
Thanks for all!
(Batch is evil ...)

Answer (score 0):

So I made it, if someone is interested in the method. I did it using batch command :

```
@echo off
set "num=0"

REM copy the file, since we are modifying it, we'll need this one to recreate the file once it's finished
xcopy %1 %1.tmp

:again
REM if file is empty, we've done it so we can stop.
if "%~z1" == "" ( 
    echo File doesnt exist. 
) else if "%~z1" == "0" ( 
    goto stop
) else ( 
    echo File is not empty
)

REM take the first line
set /p firstline=<%1
echo %firstline%

REM create a tmp file where we have remove the first line
more +1 %1 > tmp.ptx 

REM take the second line 
set /p line=<tmp.ptx
echo %line%

REM del the tmp file
del aaaa.ptx

REM XY is the number of line we will copy
set /a "XY= %line% * %firstline%" + 10
echo %XY%
set /a num+=1

REM head is a script that give you the first X lines of a file.
call head %1 %XY% > "%num%.ptx"

REM create a file having only the little file remainging
more +%XY% %1 > tmp.ptx
del %1
REN tmp.ptx %1
goto again

REM once everything is finished, juste make it as if nothing happened...
:stop
del %1
REN %1.tmp %1
pause
```

and head.bat :

```
@powershell -command "& {get-content %1|select-object -first %2}"
```

I hope it will help someone in the future.